# Tools to convert sql query to linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I write sql query for many year but I am new to linq.  Are there any tools to convert sql query to linq(especially linq to entity) so as that I can learn linq faster?

Comment: You can usually translate them manually part by part by using the [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) as reference.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried  [sqlToLinq](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) ?  There is a trial version available.

Note: I have not worked on this tool

Answer (score 0):

There are no such tools that give you 100 % accurate results. Linqer(www.sqltolinq.com) may help you in simple queries only. I advice you purchase Linqpad tool which can help practice the linq to entities. You simply write your linq and see the data results as well as the executed T-SQL. Good Luck